# Can't seem to mod_rewrite paths that actually exist

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite as follows:

`RewriteRule ^abc([.]*)$ /abc.py$1`

This works if abc is not a directory. I.e. http://eg.com/abc will show the abc.py page as desired, however if I `mkdir abc` in the root then http://eg.com/abc will actually show the contents of the abc directory.

How do I make the rewrite show the file `/abc.py` if `/abc` is a directory?

Comment: I think this belongs in webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Maybe. If that's true then so do these 4146 questions: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mod_rewrite

Comment: There's a reason that we have over 4000 questions tagged with htaccess and over 5000 questions tagged with mod-rewrite on stackoverflow, I imagine. There are a comparatively tiny amount of such questions on webmasters.stackexchange. That said, I've never used webmasters.stackexchange, so it's not clear to me where this should go.

Comment: you make a good point, also a lot of these questions may have originated before webmasters existed

Comment: see this discussion for further guidance: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67580/do-mod-rewrite-questions-belong-on-server-fault-or-webmasters

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^abc(.*)$ /abc.py$1 [R]
```

For me it works just fine.
With `[R]` you will see the result more easily.
You can also try adding `RewriteBase /` to the .htaccess file before the RewriteRule.

When I used [.] instead of just . I couldn't make the Rewrite work at all, so I wasn't really able to reproduce your issue exactly, but hope this is of any help.

Comment: That `[R]` causes a redirect, which is not what I want. I want the url to continue to be `eg.com/abc`, not `eg.com/abc.py`. Also for some reason `.` doesn't work for me, I need to use `[.]`.

Comment: Yeah, but while debugging [R] is great, since you "see" the result while playing around. You can just remove it later when you are done. :) I am not sure why [.] works for you and not for me, and vice versa, though, and also why I don't get the same problem as you do when having a folder with the name. :/ Sorry, can't be of much more use then when I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Well, the rule "works" with [R], but not without [R]. So it doesn't really help for debugging in this case. Thanks anyway :)